# ReferenceError onclick JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to run a function from `script.js` when a user clicks on a paragraph but it gives me `ReferenceError: stockClicked is not defined`.

My HTML is:

```
<p id="stock" onclick="stockClicked()"></p>
<script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
```

And the `stockClicked()` function is define in `script.js`:

```
function stockClicked() {
  console.log("here");
}
```

Comment: you have double `""`at your src.

Comment: sorry,  mistake from when I wrote the question, doesn't change anything

Comment: You are including the script after your HTML element that uses it.  It either needs to be before, or modified so it attaches the event to the element after the DOM has completed loading.

Comment: How would you modify it so it attaches after the DOM has loaded?

Comment: i would try adding the script before. also can you attempt to open your console and console.log(stockClicked) to make sure that its on the page. possibly you need to add ./ in front of script.js to make sure its loading from the correct path.

Comment: That's not necessarily true. As long as the click happens after the script is loaded, the order shouldn't matter. But @Amy is right that you should also flip the order just to be safe.

Comment: I can't move the script before the HTML because I need it after for other parts of my code to work. Is there any other way to call a function onclick?

Comment: `document.getElementById('stock').addEventListener('click', stockClicked)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you reference a script with `type="module"`, it gets loaded as an [ES6 module](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/), rather than in global scope. If you want `stockClicked()` to be available globally, just remove `type="module"` from the script tag.

If you really need to use `type="module"`, then you have a couple of options:

1. Create a new inline module script tag that imports from `script.js` and assigns the `stockClicked()` function to the global scope explicitly, by saying `window.stockClicked = stockClicked`.
2. Add the click listener programmatically instead of in HTML. In other words, after the `p` tag, add an inline script that gets the element by id and adds a click listener. Something like this:

```
import {stockClicked} from './script.js';

document.getElementById("stock").addEventListener("click", stockClicked);
```

In both cases, you need to export the `stockClicked()` function from `script.js`. Also, it's recommended to name module files with `.mjs` instead of `.js`.

Comment: I need the `type=module` because I'm importing a class into `script.js` and it won't work without it?

Comment: Edited the answer to include a couple of options.

Comment: This is a reasonable answer based on the code presented in the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the `type="module"`, then you have to bind the click event in the script itself

```js
function stockClicked() {
  console.log('here');
}

document.getElementById('stock').addEventListener('click', stockClicked);
```

```html
<p id="stock">click here</p>
```